# PHP - Fast way to Convert JSON Object into Variables

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON object that can be echoed to view in a browser as follows:

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [webmaster] => "data"
        [analytics] => "data"
        [facebook] => "data"
        [twitter] => "data"
        [maintenance] => 1
    )
```

data are other values.

I get the above output using:

```
    $data = json_decode($domainSpecific);
    print_r($data);
```

what would be a good way to convert this JSON data into 5 variables preferably with the names of the JSON values - $webmaster, $analytics, $facebook, $twitter, $maintenance?

thankyou

Comment: You mean dinamically? That's it, if you add another property to the object like... `myspace` it would have to create automatically a var called `$myspace`?

Comment: yes during php execution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode($domainSpecific);
foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
    $$key=$value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not sure why would you do that and I'm also not sure if this is a good way to program, here you have something that works as I've tried:

```
class Test {
    public $webmaster, $analytics, $facebook, $twitter, $manteinance;
}

$test = new Test();
$test->webmaster = 'Trololo';

$object_vars = get_object_vars($test);

foreach ($object_vars as $varname => $value) {
    $$varname = $value;
}

echo $webmaster; //Trololo
```

Answer (score 1):

try this [php extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
$data = json_decode($domainSpecific, TRUE);

extract($data , EXTR_PREFIX_SAME);
```

***edit***

yes you need to do json_decode with true parameter to return as array

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = extract(json_decode($domainSpecific, true));
print_r($data);
```